# Split dataframe by row at first instance

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to split a dataframe into two pieces by rows at the first instance of a certain value i.e., not splitting by groups. For example, if my data is:

```
patid disease
3     Z
99    B
4     A
1002  B
43    A
745   C
399   Z
545   A 
8     A
```

I would like two dataframes from this, the first dataframe to contain the first two patid rows and the second to contain all of the others i.e., I am splitting from the first instances of disease A. Ultimately I will discard everything that came before A, i.e., the first two occurrences of diseases B and Z.

Please note, I cannot order the rows in any way as these are time-course (medical history) records.

I can do this in a loop, easy! However, I know that R does not favour loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is using `which.max` to get the index of first occurrence of "A" in `disease` column and get all the rows after that.

```
df[which.max(df$disease == "A"):nrow(df), ]

#  patid disease
#3     4       A
#4  1002       B
#5    43       A
#6   745       C
#7   399       Z
#8   545       A
#9     8       A
```

---

and the same thing could also be achieved with `match`

```
df[match("A", df$disease):nrow(df), ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If your ultimate goal is to subset the data, you can do this directly:

```
subset(df, cumsum(disease == "A") >= 1)
#  patid disease
#3     4       A
#4  1002       B
#5    43       A
#6   745       C
#7   399       Z
#8   545       A
#9     8       A
```

But if you want to split the data, you can do it similarly:

```
split(df, cumsum(df$disease == "A") >= 1)
# $`FALSE`
# patid disease
# 1     3       Z
# 2    99       B
# 
# $`TRUE`
# patid disease
# 3     4       A
# 4  1002       B
# 5    43       A
# 6   745       C
# 7   399       Z
# 8   545       A
# 9     8       A
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use which.min and grepl function altogether:

```
df[which.min(!grepl("A", df[,"disease"])):nrow(df),]
```

Obtaining

```
  patid disease
3     4       A
4  1002       B
5    43       A
6   745       C
7   399       Z
8   545       A
9     8       A
```